# ASP.NET Core 7 : input element not rendering the tag when the page is loaded

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 MVC. I have a problem when running the code locally with the rendering of input tags that call a method in the page handler.

The page accepts a guid as a parameter:

```
@page "{Id:guid?}"
```

This is my input tag in the `.cshtml`:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-success" 
       asp-page-handler="update" value="Update">
```

This is the method signature in the `.cshtml.cs` file

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostUpdate()
```

When I run the code in production and inspect the element for the input I see this and it calls the method in the `.cshtml.cs` file:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-success" 
       value="Update" 
       formaction="/Configuration/Edit/687ddede-92ab-ed11-ac20-0003fff5e8cd?handler=update">
```

When I'm running locally and inspect the element for the input I see this and nothing hits the method in the `.cshtml.cs` file

```
<input type="submit" id="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-success" 
       asp-page-handler="update" value="Update">
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to be able to debug my code locally?

Comment: I tested your codes, it renders well on my local computer. Is your form method using "get" or "post"?

Comment: @QiangFu the form method is "post"

Comment: Have you solve this issue?